# How to use powershell to determine which PC an Active Directory user is logged into

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

I am working on an application to allow system administrators to log out a user who has left their station. Do do so I need to determine which PC the user is logged into. According to ChatGPT (possibly the worst source of information) I have this code:

```
param(
[string]$targetUsername
)

$lastLogonEvent = Get-WinEvent -LogName Security -FilterXPath "*[System[(EventID=4624) and (EventData[Data[@Name='TargetUserName']='$targetUsername'])]]" | Sort-Object TimeCreated -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

if ($lastLogonEvent -ne $null) {
    $lastLogonComputer = $lastLogonEvent.Properties[5].Value
    return $lastLogonComputer
}
```

Which I attempt to run this using `./test.ps1 *username*` I am getting errors that I don't understand.

```
Get-WinEvent : No events were found that match the specified selection criteria.
At C:\test.ps1:5 char:19
+ $lastLogonEvent = Get-WinEvent -LogName Security -FilterXPath "*[System[(EventID ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-WinEvent], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchingEventsFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand
```

How do I make this work, or is there another means I can use to get this information. I am calling the script out of a C# application, either as a .ps1 file or as a script invocation directly from the code.

Comment: Events are great for looking back, but if you want to know who has an active logon session _right now_, you'll probably want to query WMI for logon sessions, eg. `Get-CimInstance Win32_LoggedOnUser |% Antecedent |? Name -eq $targetUsername`